# to display 3 columns in 1 row in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to display 3 columns in a row using map method but it is not showing.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import _ from "lodash";


const MoviesGrid = props => {
  const { movies } = props;

  const chunked = _.chunk(movies, 3);

  return chunked.map(i => (
    <div className="row-movies" key={i}>
      {i.map(movie => (
        <div className="col-movies" key={movie.id}>
          {
            <ul key={movie._id}>
              <li>{movie.title}</li>
              <li>{movie.genre.name}</li>
              <li>{movie.numberInStock}</li>
              <li>{movie.dailyRentalRate}</li>
            </ul>
          }
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  ));
};

export default MoviesGrid;
```

It is displaying 9 rows on the server.

Comment: Can you post some sample data of `movies `?

Comment: It is displaying 9 rows on the server? what do you mean by the server? what is the CSS for `row-movies` ?

Answer (score 0):

I have no trouble here, maybe try to remove the `{ }` around your `<ul>`?

```js
const movies = [
  {title: 'Movie 1', genre: {name: 'Comedy'}, numberInStock: 1, dailyRentalRate: 1},
  {title: 'Movie 2', genre: {name: 'Comedy'}, numberInStock: 1, dailyRentalRate: 1},
  {title: 'Movie 3', genre: {name: 'Action'}, numberInStock: 1, dailyRentalRate: 1},
  {title: 'Movie 4', genre: {name: 'SF'}, numberInStock: 1, dailyRentalRate: 1},
]


const MoviesGrid = props => {
  const { movies } = props;

  const chunked = _.chunk(movies, 3);

  return chunked.map(i => (
    <div className="row-movies" key={i}>
      {i.map(movie => (
        <div className="col-movies" key={movie.id}>
          <ul key={movie._id}>
            <li>{movie.title}</li>
            <li>{movie.genre.name}</li>
            <li>{movie.numberInStock}</li>
            <li>{movie.dailyRentalRate}</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  ));
};

ReactDOM.render(<MoviesGrid movies={movies} />, document.getElementById('app'))
```

```css
.row-movies {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}

.col-movies {
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```